# Custom sorting in Oracle is not working

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am working on the following query in which

```
Select name from (Select 'Mana' as name from table1
union 
Select 'Tom' as name from dual)A
order by case 
when name = 'TOM' then '1'
else name 
end ;
```

which is giving the output

```
 Mana
 Tom
```

and the result i want after the custom sorting  is

```
Tom
Mana
```

> Please don't answer for Order By desc as i have other values in the
>   column, i need custom sorting

thanks

Comment: 'Tom' is not the same as 'TOM' ...

Comment: Do you still have the same problem after changing your real code to have the same case? (Your example output now doesn't match your example code, so no idea what you're really seeing). If so, is your `name` column `char` or `varchar2`, and what character set are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing `name` with `'TOM'`, but the value you have in that column is `'Tom'` - the case doesn't match.

```
Select name from (Select 'Mana' as name from dual
union 
Select 'Tom' as name from dual)A
order by case 
when name = 'Tom' then '1'
else name 
end ;

NAME
----
Tom
Mana
```

You might prefer to add a flag to sort by, and then further sort by name:

```
Select name from (Select 'Mana' as name from dual
union 
Select 'Tom' as name from dual)A
order by case when name = 'Tom' then 1 else 2 end,
name;

NAME
----
Tom
Mana
```

That also avoids any potential issues with character sets - you're assuming that the character '1' always sorted before 'T'. (Which may be true, but still...)

Comment: The "else 2" part is not needed (by default the CASE expression will return NULL in the "else" case, and NULL is sorted last by default). Easier to read with the "else 2" - so easier on the developer, but this is really at the very basic level. Then, perhaps UPPER(name) = 'TOM' would solve some problems...

Comment: @mathguy - Yes, but I prefer the explicitness for something like this, the behaviour isn't always obvious (esp. to someone else reading it later). I'm not sure it's safe to assume that case isn't relevant to the OP - it's a contrived example (I hope - refrained from getting rid of the subquery etc.) but even so, no way to tell if they might have a value of ToM that shouldn't be sorted first. As so often, too much guesswork, so it can only be a starting point *8-)

Comment: Right. On the CASE expression: My point was that the "someone reading it later" should have no problem understanding it without the "else 2" (unless they are a student learning SQL right then). Also, when CASE is used like that repeatedly in a query, not assigning the value 2, and not comparing 1 to 2 (and instead just pushing all NULL to the end) should be more efficient, although how much so is not clear - probably not much. Anyway, that's where that come from (right or wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you need?

```
order by case 
when name = 'TOM' then 1
else 2
end ;
```

In your `order by` clause you have a `number` and `varchar` as result of `case` this cause comparing them as `varchar` pleas use same type.

```
Select name from 
  (
  Select 'Mana' as name from dual
  union all
  Select 'Tom' as name from dual
  ) A
order by 
  case 
    when upper(name) = 'TOM' then 1
    else 2
  end;
```

And please take care of `upper`/`lower` case sensitivity

Comment: No... the OP does not have a number and a varchar2; even the "number" is actually a varchar, the OP used `'1'` rather than `1`. Still not a good idea; the comparison relies on the accident of where digits fall compared to letters in the ASCII table (do digits come before letters or after?).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
order by case 
when upper(name) = 'TOM' then 1
else 2
end, name ;
```

This will keep `TOM` at top and rest sorted afterwards

Comment: It won't keep 'Tom' at the top though *8-)

Comment: Your sample data there has TOM, not Tom. The case has to match? The OP's sample data has `'Tom'`, with lower-case 'o' and 'm'.

Comment: LOL. Didn't see the case there.